# How to create a quantum algorithm that produces 2 n-bit sequences with equal number of 1-bits?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, quantum-computation

I am interested in a quantum algorithm that has the following characteristics:

1. output = 2n bits  OR 2 sets of n bits (e.g. 2 x 3 bits)
2. the number of 1-bits in the first set of n-bits must be equal to the number of 1-bits in the second set.  E.g. correct output =  `0,0,0, 0,0,0`   (both 3-bit sets have zero 1-bits); `1,0,0, 0,1,0`   (both 3-bit sets have one 1-bit); `1,1,0, 0,1,1`   (both 3-bit sets have two 1-bit)
3. Each time the quantum algorithm runs it must randomly return one of the possible solutions.  There are 2 good ways to interpret *"randomly return one of the possible solutions"*:  (1) each possible good solution has equal chance of being returned by the quantum algorithm. (2) every possible good solution has a chance > 0 of being returned.

Any idea how I can best implement such an algorithm on a quantum computer ?

FYI I have tried the following algorithm (where n = 2 ) but it missed the 2 answers 0110 and 1001.
[screenshot of the quantum circuit + simulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3tzL.jpg)

Comment: Classical algorithms are a special case of quantum algorithms, so why not just use an easy classical algorithm?

Comment: I am just learning about quantum computing.  Understanding how simple problems can be translated into a quantum algorithm would hopefully help me some day to create quantum algorithms for problems that can not be handled by classical algorithms in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: the quantum algorithm would provide a true random number generator (which a classical algorithm cannot)

Comment: Questions liek this are well-received at quantumcomputing.stackexchange

Comment: thanks for the comment - I have cross posted the question : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-to-create-a-quantum-algorithm-that-produces-2-n-bit-sequences-with-equal-num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this, for concreteness described for $n=2$: Start with two registers of $2$ qubits, initialised as $|00\rangle|00\rangle$; apply a Hadamard transformation to each of the qubits in the first register, resulting in
$$(|00\rangle+|10\rangle+|01\rangle+|11\rangle)|00\rangle$$
(I leave out the normalisation factor). Then apply a sequence of CNOT gates with qubit $p\in\{1,2,3\}$ from register 1 as control and qubit $p$ from register 2 as target. This produces the entangled state
$$|00\rangle|00\rangle+|11\rangle|11\rangle+|10\rangle|10\rangle+|01\rangle|01\rangle$$
To obtain also the permutations $|10\rangle|01\rangle$ and $|01\rangle|10\rangle$ perform a [square-root-of-SWAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Square_root_of_Swap_gate_(%E2%88%9AS)) operation $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$ on the qubits in the second register.
<sub>recall that $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}|\alpha\beta\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\alpha\beta\rangle+i|\beta\alpha\rangle\right)$</sub>
The resulting state is
$$(1+i)|00\rangle|00\rangle+(1+i)|11\rangle|11\rangle+
|10\rangle(|10\rangle+i|01\rangle)+|01\rangle(|01\rangle+i|10\rangle)$$
Finally measure the qubits in both registers to obtain a random output. The weights are such that there is equal probability to obtain one of the even parity terms (0000, 1111) as one of the odd parity terms (1010, 1001, 0101, 0110).

Comment: I have tried to simulate your algorithm (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3tzL.jpg) for n=2 but it missed the 2 correct answers 0110 and 1001.

Comment: indeed, I fixed that with a square-root-of-SWAP

Comment: I just noticed that the cross-posted question on [quantumcomputing.stackexchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-to-create-a-quantum-algorithm-that-produces-2-n-bit-sequences-with-equal-num) follows a different approach using $n^2$ ancilla qubits in addition to the $2n$ data qubits to carry out the permutation. Which algorithm you prefer may depend on the available resources...

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer - I am still figuring out how to simulate this. (https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/community/question?questionId=5b13af6b5be4cd0037d41b9a).

Comment: FYI for the permuation issue I have created a separate question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301940/how-to-permute-reshuffle-an-n-bit-input-using-a-quantum-algorithm

Comment: I finally managed to validate this on IBM composer using the following implementation of $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$ : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer .  And exactly like you already predicted the even parity terms (0000, 1111) are double as likely as the odd parity terms.  Excellent.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker It seems unclear how to generalize this to $n>2$. Also, if you are willing to accept any probability distribution, why not just output a fixed solution?

Comment: FYI: I have clarified "randomly chosen" in the question.